# Remove black edges / borders (underscan) from monitor and fix bluriness on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: screen, display-resolution, monitor

Title is self explanatory, and the blurriness is actually due to the underscan. I'm just posting this so I can answer it myself, since I struggled with this for ages.

Answer (score 1):

Despite having set `xrandr --output <display_name> underscan off` (and every other setting under the sun), when I did the following that was when my issue was fixed:

```
xrandr --output HDMI-A-0 --set "underscan vborder" 0
xrandr --output HDMI-A-0 --set "underscan hborder" 0
```

I hope this is permanent, but I don't think so. That's the next step, but at least it's working for now!